# How to set width so that it will be able to be divided by some value

Tags: html, css, rounding, divide

I need to create table with width 90% of page. But I also need to make special grid. Some cells are 2*3, some 2*1, some 3*2, 1*1 and so on. "1" is one ninth of table width. So, my target is to delete gaps between cells, they appear because of rounding. What is the best way to achieve it? I have already made html code with required colspans and rowspans. It takes the required form if I set width 33.33% for cell with colspan 3 and so on.

So, I understand, that I need to make width dividable by 9 for perfect situation. For example, I can add or subtract from 1 to 4 pixels using javascript, but I think it isn't very good way.

Also, I need to set width in percents in special way - if I just write 11.11%, 22.22%, 33.33% and so on, I still have gaps. But if I change first cell width from 33.33% to 33.32%, and add 0.02% to last(for example), it becomes ok, no gaps really. At least in Chrome. I know, that rounding is different in different browsers. So I'm searching for the best way to set these percents(or smth else) to make it perfect.

I don't really believe, that it can be realized without javascript, using just css, but I still hope.

So, I will be very grateful to any helpful ideas.

Sorry for bad english :)

Comment: Could u use fiddle or something like that? a wireframe would be very appreciated for understanding better. Thanks

Comment: It is smth like this http://jsfiddle.net/m0Lsdvnd/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Masonry could be the right solution for you http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: It seems to be! I'll check it a bit later and comment, thank you)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is little for other purposes.. This library just helps to create grid, but I've already did it, I just need to make everything perfect, one-to-one pixel..